# 404 Not Found error when routing using silex

Tags: php, silex

I had the following code, which worked fine on PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.2. I think I simply upgraded my apache to 2.4 and it seems to have stopped working.

```
api
-app
   -job
     -jobController.php
     -jobFacade.php
     -jobFacadeProvider.php
   -src
     -BatchAutoscalingApplication.php
     -routes.php
   -app.php
   -index.php
```

routes.php

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . "/../job/JobController.php";
    $app->mount("/job", new JobController());
?>
```

jobCOntroller.php

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ ."/JobFacade.php";

    class JobController implements ControllerProviderInterface
    {
        public function connect(Application $app)
        {

            $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
            error_log("isnide cntroller",false);
            $controllers->get('/isAcceptable', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

                $id_contents = $request->query->get('id_contents');
                $result = $app['job']->isAcceptable($id_contents, $id_host, $id_vhost, $private_ip);
                return new JsonResponse($result);
            });

            return $controllers;
        }

        public function boot(Application $app)
        {
            // TODO: Implement boot() method.
        }
    }
?>
```

jobFacade.php

```
class JobFacade
    {
        public function isAcceptable($id_contents)
        {
           return "something"
        }
    }
```

JobFacadeProvider.php

```
class JobFacadeProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
    {
        public function register(Application $app) {
            $app['job'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
                return new JobFacade();
            });
        }
        public function boot(Application $app) {}
}
```

index.php

```
 $app = require_once __DIR__ . '/app/app.php';
    $app->after($app["cors"]);

    $app->run();

?>
```

BatchAutoscalingApplication.php

```
class BatchAutoScalingApplication extends Application
    {
        public function __construct(array $values = array())
        {
            parent::__construct($values);
            $this->register(new CorsServiceProvider(), array(
                "cors.allowOrigin" => "*",
            ));

            $this->register(new JobFacadeProvider());

        }

    }
```

app.php

```
$app = new BatchAutoScalingApplication();

    require_once __DIR__ . '/src/routes.php';

    return $app;

?>
```

When I hit the url `http://<host>/job/isAcceptable?id_contents=34`, it gives me the following error

`404 Not Found`
`The requested URL /job/isAcceptable was not found on this server`

PS: The DocumentRoot is pointed to the `api` directory.

Answer (score 1):

It was a silly mistake. I simply added `AllowOverride All` in my `httpd.conf` and it now seems to work ok.